# Sequelize mapping does not work using max and col

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, mapping

I am using sequelize 5.21.8 and I have to calculate the min and max of a column, so I use `fn.min` and `fn.max` .

My mapping is like so

```
startTime: {
  field:'signaldate',
  type: Sequelize.DATE
} ,
```

and for that column my query is

```
    return Signals.findAll({
      attributes:[
        [Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('signaldate')), 'maxdateallowed'],
        [Sequelize.fn('min', Sequelize.col('signaldate')), 'maxdateallowed']
      ]   
    })
```

The problem is that I have to use the original column name inside the `Sequelize.fn('max'`, in the `Sequelize.col` part. The query works, but the mapping does snot.

If I use the `startTime` as I set in the mapping, like so

```
    [Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('startTime')), 'maxdateallowed'],
```

then I get an error

> SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'startTime' in 'field list'

How can I use mapping in that case and not have an error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution mentioned in the below Git issue as a workaround, there is no permanent fix yet.
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10732

This issue generic to `sequalize.col()` and not specific to `'max'` and `'min'`.

Answer (score -1):

The mapping does not work because you are mapping the `max` and `min` to the same column `maxdateallowed`. For the `min` map it to something like **min**dateallowed (`mindateallowed`)

```
return Signals.findAll({
    attributes: [
        [Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('signaldate')), 'maxdateallowed'],
        [Sequelize.fn('min', Sequelize.col('signaldate')), 'mindateallowed']
    ]
})
```

Comment: Even if you map correctly, it would throw the error that @codebot has mentioned.